# Routing and URL Creation - Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii, routes, yii2

I have a url in my webapp:

```
https://domain/store/cuisine?category=33
```

i want to create a route to:

```
https://domain/destiny to https://domain/cuisine?category=33
```

I added:

```
'edobhi' => 'store/cuisine?category=33',
```

on urlManager but i got 404.

How can i route this?

Answer (score 0):

Look here https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing#default-parameter-values

So your rule will look something like this:

```
'rules' => [
    // ...other rules...
    [
        'pattern' => 'edobhi',
        'route' => 'store/cuisine',
        'defaults' => ['category' => 33],
    ],
]
```

Now you can access `https://domain/edobhi` that will be mapped to `StoreController` and action `actionCuisine` with param `$category=33`